# Vue.js cannot understand the problem here

Tags: laravel, vue.js

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="list-group">

      <li class="list-group-item" v-for="p in list" :key="p.id">{{ p.id }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

the list is always shown as empty. the console print is

> {**ob**: Observer} data: Array(2) 0: {**ob**: Observer} 1: {**ob**:
>   Observer} length: 2
>   **ob**: Observer {value: Array(2), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
>   **proto**: Array
>   **ob**: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0} get data: ƒ reactiveGetter() set data: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
>   **proto**: Object

```
<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      list: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.lp();
  },

  methods: {
    lp: function() {
      console.log("Fetching portfolios...");
      axios
        .get("api/portfolios")

        .then(response => {
          this.list = response.data.data;
          console.log(this.list); //console prints the data
        })
        .catch(error => { 
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Please share your controller as well.

Comment: Seems the axios request is failing, causing the console.log in the catch to be run. Look in the network tab in your browser inspector. Any requests failing?

Comment: actually axios is working fine, I can receive json data and the console print is for two entries of the json array. In network tab, I can get json response too. The problem seems in the display of those data.

Comment: Can you paste, `response` object

Comment: And my controller method 
`public function index() {`
`return PortfolioResource::collection(Portfolio::all());`
`}`

Comment: The response is as : 
`(2) [{…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
0: {__ob__: Observer}
1: {__ob__: Observer}
length: 2
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(2), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array`

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is the part of the arrow function:

```
.then(response => {
   this.list = response.data.data;
})
```

in this case the `this` doesn't refer to the vue object. Instead you should use the function [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) like so:

```
.then(function(response) {
   this.list = response.data.data;
}.bind(this))
```

Now the `this` reference in the function is a reference to the vue object.

Comment: I can get the data in console.log(this.list) i.e two entries of json array. The problem remains same after using bind(this). The v-for cannot render data. But the console shows the data.

Comment: The response is as :
`(2) [{…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
0: {__ob__: Observer}
1: {__ob__: Observer}
length: 2
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(2), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array`